Get count of each email type PER table
Following up on from my previous question
I had to get clarification. So I do indeed need to have multiple tables.
I then need to get a count of all the 'gmails', 'msfts', 'others', and 'vmgs' from each table.
All the tables have the same design.  Table1 may resemble this:
| EMAIL | MY_ISP | STATUS |
 -------------------------
| email1| gmail  | active |
 -------------------------
| email2| msft   | unsub  |
 -------------------------
| email3| vmg    | active |
 -------------------------
| email4| gmail  | active |
 -------------------------

With table2 possibly looking like this:
| EMAIL | MY_ISP | STATUS |
 -------------------------
| email1| gmail  | unsub  |
 -------------------------
| email2| msft   | active |
 -------------------------
| email3| vmg    | active |
 -------------------------
| email5| gmail  | unsub  |
 -------------------------

An email may exist in multiple tables, but won't be listed in the same table twice.  The same email may be ACTIVE in one or more tables, and may not exist in another.
I need to get a running count of all emails per table that are ACTIVE.
And I need to display the end product this:
TABLE | GMAIL | MSFT | OTHER | VMG 
-----------------------------------
T1    | 5000  | 7000 | 4500  | 475
-----------------------------------
T2    | 4520  | 6789 | 4450  | 425
-----------------------------------
T3    | 4400  | 6500 | 4123  | 410
-----------------------------------

Something like that.  All the way down to T15.
As I keep adding more tables, the number totals should gradually decrease until they are practically 0.
I am having trouble wrapping my mind around this logic.
Per my previous question, I can get the total of the MY_ISP using this query:
SELECT COUNT(`my_isp`) AS 'COUNT', `my_isp` FROM `table1` GROUP BY `my_isp`

And will spit out something like this:
COUNT | my_isp
---------------
4000  | Gmail
---------------
2000  | MSFT
---------------
10000 | other
---------------
15000 | VMG
---------------

And I can get the totals for each MY_ISP using something like this:
select my_isp ,sum(cnt) AS total
 from (select my_isp,count(t1.`my_isp`) cnt from `table1` t1 group by my_isp
      UNION ALL
       select my_isp,count(t2.`my_isp`) cnt from `table2` t2 group by my_isp
      ) subquery_name
 group by my_isp

The above actually works splendidly.  But it's not what was requested.
So just to reiterate, I need to get a count of GMAILS, MSFT, VMG, and OTHER per each table.
How should this query look?
I will keep running tests and update question in the event I make some progress.
Edit
I'm thinking maybe I need to create a VIEW that will display the different MY_ISP as the column headers, and the each TABLE as the rows.

These should likely all be combined into one table. Perhaps ask a question about how to combine them.

@JNevill So you're suggesting extracting the data back out into an Excel and run a pivot?

I've moved my comment to an answer. When we translate row values into columns it's called a PIVOT, in fact many RDBMS have a PIVOT keyword to handle this exact scenario, Mysql is not one of them (unless it's a newly added feature that I missed). It's much like a PivotTable in excel, but implemented through code on a result set in an RDBMS. I have shared how to do that using case expressions in mysql in my answer.

The route to solve this is to either first UNION all of the tables together and then PIVOT the results to put the ISP up in the column. OR, alternatively, PIVOT each table to put ISP in the column and then UNION those together. I would opt for the first since PIVOT is expensive computationally so performing that step once would be best
This would look something like:
SELECT tablename,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ISP = 'gmail' THEN email END) as gmail,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN ISP = 'msft' THEN email END) as msft,
       COUNT(...
       COUNT(...
FROM
    (
        SELECT 't1' as tablename, my_isp, email FROm table1 
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 't2', my_isp, email FROM table2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 't3', my_isp, email FROM table3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT....
    ) sub
GROUP BY tablename
ORDER BY tablename

dbfiddle example here
I haven't looked at your linked question, but I'm sure this was discussed at length, and I feel that it needs to be added here as well since this UNION solution is a band-aid on the actual problem: Namely, all of this data should be in a single table already. A proper schema would essentially look like the output of the subquery in this answer. That may not be possible if you aren't in charge of the schema or data acquisition, but it's food for thought. Changing the schema would reduce the complexity of this query as a subquery would be unnecessary, and it would reduce the compute costs of running this thing as the data would already be properly unioned.

What does "tablename" represent?  Am I starting the SELECT with one of my tables?

tablename is merely what we are calling the new column we are generating. We are setting the value stored in that column to the string-literal t1. Your desired output in your question has a column called TABLE and that is something that you will have to set manually in your SQL, and the way we do that is through that 't1' as tablename code.

I did combine all of the data into a single table.  When I tried to run a query, everything froze.

I've added a dbfiddle to the answer to help better visualize the output using your sample/input data outlined in your question. I think it might help.

Add the table name as another column in each query in the UNION
select table_name, my_isp ,sum(cnt) AS total
from (
    select 't1' AS table_name, my_isp, count(t1.`my_isp`) cnt from `table1` t1 group by my_isp
    UNION ALL
    select 't2' AS table_name, my_isp, count(t2.`my_isp`) cnt from `table2` t2 group by my_isp
) subquery_name
group by table_name, my_isp

To get each provider into a column you can pivot the resulting data. See How can I return pivot table output in MySQL?
